# Installing `kali-win-kex` on WSL2 fails

Tags: kali-linux, dpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kexec

I tried installing Kali-Win-Kex by following [the official guide](https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/).

```
    $ sudo apt install kali-win-kex -y
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     new kali-win-kex package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying `apt install -f` solve the problem changes package status from `half-installed` to `uninstalled`.

Trying to install the package directly leads to the following error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 102450 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb ...
This package is for WSL 2. Nothing to be done here.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb (--install):
 new kali-win-kex package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb
```

How can I install `kali-win-kex`?

```
Windows version: 19042.746
Kali version: 2020.4 (kali-rolling)
```

Comment: Include the command that leads up to this error in your question.

Comment: The general command (from Kali-Win Documentation) that is used to install kex.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack.  When you ask a question, please keep in mind that *you* are the one asking others for help.  If someone suggests that you add detail to the question so that others can hopefully help you out, and then you want them (and everyone else who reads the question) to go search the Kali-Win documentation for that information, well, that's probably just not going to happen.  And you are not likely to get an answer as a result.

Comment: I updated to WSL2 and used the exact commands from the doc to install Kex, the problem here is not related with that. What clue does the error message give will help to diagnose the problem. Anyway, I ditched messing with it because it also slow. Thanks for replying.

Comment: check your wsl version `wsl -l -v` (run in power-shell or cmd); this line `This package is for WSL 2. Nothing to be done here.` says seems you are not using WSL2

Comment: There is a solution on [Installing `kali-win-kex` on WSL2 fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633735/installing-kali-win-kex-on-wsl2-fails/633736?noredirect=1#comment1186990_633736).

Answer (score 0):

You are not currently running WSL 2. If you upgrade your WSL to WSL 2, it will work.