# Installing `kali-win-kex` on WSL2 fails

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried installing `kali-win-kex` by following [the official guide](https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/).

```
    $ sudo apt install kali-win-kex -y
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     new kali-win-kex package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying `apt install -f` solve the problem changes package status from `half-installed` to `uninstalled`.

Trying to install the package directly leads to the following error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 102450 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb ...
This package is for WSL 2. Nothing to be done here.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb (--install):
 new kali-win-kex package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-win-kex_2.7_amd64.deb
```

How can I install `kali-win-kex`?

```
Windows version: 19042.746
Kali version: 2020.4 (kali-rolling)
```

**NOTE**: This should probably be the same as [this question: Cannot install Kali-WIn-Kex because of Dpkg error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632633/cannot-install-kali-win-kex-because-of-dpkg-error) but reviewer decided this should be a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `kali-win-kex` tests for WSL2 by checking if `/mnt/wsl` exists but it seems WSL is not creating that directory.

To install this package:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/wsl
$ sudo apt install -y kali-win-kex
```

Comment: Creating `/mnt/wsl` in this way might fix the install problem, but is not a good long-term solution, as it will break the inter-instance file transfer mechanism.  Better to figure out why WSL isn't creating it automatically in Kali.  Do you happen to have a `/etc/wsl.conf`?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds the long term solution is to use a better test for WSL2, [a solution proposal is already submitted upstream](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/kali-win-kex/-/merge_requests/2).

Comment: I'm just saying that if your answer recommends that people create a directory that will interfere with WSL functionality, it should at least also include deleting the manually created "wrong version" of the directory after the kex installation is completed.